# SSE instructions in ASM function

Tags: assembly, sse

I am trying to use SSE instructions in order to improve the speed of my ASM function. This function actually does the negative of bitmap. Here is my code without SSE which gets array of bytes and array size. And it fully works, does the negative of bitmap.

```
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
.586 

.MODEL flat, stdcall


OPTION CASEMAP:NONE

INCLUDE    include\windows.inc
INCLUDE    include\user32.inc
INCLUDE    include\kernel32.inc 

.CODE

DllEntry PROC hInstDLL:HINSTANCE, reason:DWORD, reserved1:DWORD

    mov eax, TRUE  
    ret

DllEntry ENDP

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Negatyw24 PROC stdcall uses eax ebx ecx edx, tab :dword, amount :dword

    mov EAX, tab    ;kopiuj adres 1 komorki
    add EAX, amount ;dodaj ilosc komorek
    sub EAX, 1      ;przjedz do ost komorki
petla:

    mov BL, [EAX]   ;pobierz komorke do rej
    mov CL, 255     ;laduj FF do CL
    sub CL, BL      ;neguj bajt w BL
    mov [EAX], CL   ;zapisz zaneg bajt do pao
    cmp EAX, tab    ;sprawdz koniec tablicy
    je koniec
    sub EAX, 1      ;przesun sie w tablicy o 1 komorke do tylu
    jmp petla
koniec: 

    ret 

Negatyw24 ENDP

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

END DllEntry
```

And now I wanted to make the same operation but using MMX registers. I have done something like this, tried a few other ways and nothing worked. Can someone help me with this? Here is my actual code:

```
    ;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
.686 
.mmx
.xmm
.MODEL flat, stdcall


OPTION CASEMAP:NONE

INCLUDE    include\windows.inc
INCLUDE    include\user32.inc
INCLUDE    include\kernel32.inc 

.CODE

DllEntry PROC hInstDLL:HINSTANCE, reason:DWORD, reserved1:DWORD

    mov eax, TRUE  
    ret

DllEntry ENDP

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Negatyw24 PROC stdcall uses eax ebx ecx edx edi esi, tab :dword, amount :dword

    mov EAX, tab    ;adres początku tablicy
    add EAX, amount ;dodaj ilosc komorek
    sub EAX, 1      ;przejdz do ostatniej komorki

    mov EBX, 112    ;ilosc bajtow przeksztalcanych w jednym cyklu MMX

    pcmpeqd xmm0, xmm0

    ; -----------------------
    ; Petla negowania z SSE -
    ; -----------------------

    petlaSSE:
        cmp EAX, tab    ;jesli zostalo mniej niz 112 bajtow
        je koniecSSE    ;to koniec instrukcji SSE

        movaps xmm1, [EAX]
        ;movaps xmm1, [EAX-1]
        ;movaps xmm1, [EAX-2]
        ;movaps xmm1, [EAX-3]
        ;movaps xmm1, [EAX-4]
        ;movaps xmm1, [EAX-5]
        ;movaps xmm1, [EAX-6]

        pxor    xmm1, xmm0                  ; zanegowanie wartości rejestrów
        ;pxor   xmm2, xmm0
        ;pxor   xmm3, xmm0
        ;pxor   xmm4, xmm0
        ;pxor   xmm5, xmm0
        ;pxor   xmm6, xmm0
        ;pxor   xmm7, xmm0

        movaps [EAX], xmm1
        ;movaps [EAX-1], xmm2
        ;movaps [EAX-2], xmm3
        ;movaps [EAX-3], xmm4
        ;movaps [EAX-4], xmm5
        ;movaps [EAX-5], xmm6
        ;movaps [EAX-6], xmm7

        sub EAX, 7  ;zmniejszenie komorek o 7

        jmp petlaSSE

    koniecSSE:  

    ret 

Negatyw24 ENDP

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

END DllEntry
```

Comment: Define _"nothing worked"_. In what way did it not work? How did the result differ from the one you expected? What have you done in terms of debugging?

Comment: You're making a lot of work for yourself - you could just do this in C, and use SSE intrinsics if needed - you'd get similar (perhaps even better) performance, for around 10% of the grief compared to doing this in asm.

Comment: "nothing worked" means "got weird error that *doesn't* say that the problem was a misaligned address in an aligned load", however, that was the problem. It's either misaligned the first time or the second time, guaranteed by the `sub eax, 7`.

Comment: "nothing worked" meant: heap corruption, memory error or just crashing of application. And I have to do it in ASM, that is a part of my project.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems. You seem to have forgotten that `xmm` registers are 16 bytes, instead pretending to process 7 bytes per iteration and starting at "1 before the end" (and then sticking out past the end by 15 bytes).

Fortunately the aligned loads caught it, otherwise you would have gotten a completely broken output and one of the most annoying things to debug: *occasional* crashes, possibly in unrelated code.

You could use unaligned loads if you fixed the first problem, but then you still have to make sure you handle an eventual "end of the array" correctly (if the length is not a multiple of 16, inverting the partial piece at the end would break whatever happens to be there).

As an aside, using 2 jumps per loop iteration is not necessary, you can do it with 1.

Fixing everything makes a lot of code, it's easier to guarantee that the array will be 16-aligned and have a length divisible by 16. If you can't make those guarantees, here's some code (not tested) that I adapted from a routine that works so this probably does too:

```
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp + 8]
    mov ecx, [ebp + 12]
    pcmpeqb xmm0, xmm0
    test al, 15
    jz aligned_entry
unaligned:
    not byte ptr [eax]
    add eax, 1
    sub ecx, 1
    jz exit
    test al, 15
    jnz unaligned
aligned_entry:
    sub ecx, 32
    jb tail
aligned:  ; unrolled by 2 (32 bytes / iteration), was optimal on my old PC
    movdqa xmm1, [eax]
    pxor xmm1, xmm0
    movdqa [eax], xmm1
    movdqa xmm1, [eax + 16]
    pxor xmm1, xmm0
    movdqa [eax + 16], xmm1
    add eax, 32
    sub ecx, 32
    ja aligned
tail:
    add ecx, 32
    jz exit
tail_loop:
    not byte ptr [eax]
    add eax, 1
    sub ecx, 1
    jnz tail_loop
exit:
    leave
    ret
```

You can leave out the alignment loop and the tail loop if you allocate a proper buffer. Those parts are not particularly efficiently coded, because they don't have to be - most of the work is in the middle.

Comment: Okay, I know how it works in theory but I can't do it in practice... even with your example code. I have no skills in writing in ASM and would like just to get over with this...

Comment: @Infinito you can pretty much copy and paste this, no? Maybe adapt it to stdcall

Comment: Fine then, but according to your example what is in ebp, esp in first lines? My array?

Comment: @Infinito that stuff is for the stack frame, not really required here but that way it looks better in many debuggers

Comment: I am really confused... could you adapt this alignement to my code please?